# Returning a custom response code for for serving static html when using IIS ApplicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo feature?

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, warm-up

I'm currently using the [ApplicationInitialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/) feature of IIS to warm up my ASP.NET application. I've set the attribute **remapManagedRequestsTo** to **"warmup.html"**.

```
<applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="warmup.html" skipManagedModules="true" doAppInitAfterRestart="true" >
  <add initializationPage="/home" />  
  <add initializationPage="/about-us" />      
</applicationInitialization>
```

It's working well but I would like to return a custom status code when the content for Warmup.html is returned to the browser. This is so that when I run some smoke tests after deployment I get to know when the warm up has finished.

I've tried using [URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to change the status code from 200 to 555 to serve up **warmup.html** and it does change the status code but doesn't serve the content in **warmup.html**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Change warm up status code" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="warmup.html" />          
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="555" subStatusCode="0"/>        
  </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Is there a way I can do both the serving of **warmup.html**'s content **AND** return a custom status code of **555**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found my answer in a blog post written by [Morten Bock](https://blog.mortenbock.dk/2018/02/14/how-to-add-a-warming-up-message-to-your-umbraco-site/)

Turns out I have to remove the two attributes **remapManagedRequestsTo** and  **skipManagedModules** (default value of false) which leaves us with

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
  <add initializationPage="/home" />  
  <add initializationPage="/about-us" />      
</applicationInitialization>
```

Then let the URL Rewrite module take over but we want to rewrite the response code when the Application Initialization is making the request marked by the server variable `APP_WARMING_UP` containing a value of `1`. When this condition is met we can create a custom response as the action and pop the statusCode attribute with 555.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="WarmUp" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{APP_WARMING_UP}" pattern="1" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="555" statusReason="Site is warming up" statusDescription="Try again shortly" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then to catch the status 555 as a custom error and direct the user to the friendly warm up page **warmup.html**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <error statusCode="555" path="warmup.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This answer is really helpful. Thanks!